# Creating dynamic CSS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, setattribute, createelement

I am trying to create an info window for Google maps and need to generate a dynamic form to display information.

The following scripts generates an error called **"No_found_err: DOM exception 8"**:

```
//create objects for HTML elements              
var inputElement1 = document.createElement("input");
var inputElement2 = document.createElement("input");

//assign different attributes to the element
inputElement1.setAttribute("type", "text");
inputElement1.setAttribute("id", "poiName");
inputElement2.setAttribute("type", "textarea");
inputElement2.setAttribute("id", "poiDesc");

//create style tag, atrributes and values
//add css style to head tag and define classname for HTML "desctag" element
var cssNode = document.createElement("style");
cssNode.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
cssNode.style.cssText = ".cssClass {vertical-align: text-top; width: 250px; height: 150px }";

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild("cssNode");
document.getElementById("poiDesc").className = "cssClass";

var formString = "<b>Enter location details:</b>
<p>Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + inputElement1 + "<br>Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;" + inputElement2 +
"<p><center>" + "<input type='button' id='saveBtn' value='Save' onclick='savePOI()'>  
</center>";

//insert values into the form elements      
document.getElementById("poiName").value = locList[i].name;
**document.getElementById("poiDesc").value = locList[i].desc;**
```

This error appears in between the last two lines. Does it mean that the tag id "poiName" and/or "poiDesc" have not been created?

How can I solve the above problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What browser do you get this error in? I think it would say something differently if the elements "poiName" or "poiDesc" weren't found. What is `locList`?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild("cssNode");` should be `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssNode);` notice `cssNode` isn't quoted, you passed a string to append Child instead of the node.

`inputElement1` and `inputElement1` are elements not string, so appending them to an html string wont give the desired results. Also you never add them or the html string to the dom, so  `document.getElementById` wont be able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instead you should use `inputElement1` and `inputElement2`.

document.getElementById() gets an element with the id in the document. The document does not have it until now. It will only when rendered.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, this code needs to be changed from:

```
cssNode.style.cssText = ".cssClass {vertical-align: text-top; width: 250px; height: 150px }";
```

to:

```
cssNode.innerText = ".cssClass {vertical-align: text-top; width: 250px; height: 150px }";
```

Your code was doing the equivalent of this:

```
<style type='text/css' style='.cssClass {vertical-align: text-top; width: 250px; height: 150px }'></style>
```

(incidently, since the style string includes the class and the braces, it's invalid when used in this way. This means you actually create `<style type='text/css'></style>` )

While I assume it was your intention to do this (formatting added for clarity)

```
<style>
  .cssClass 
  { 
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
  }
</style>
```

Here's a complete example of (a) creating style elements on the fly (b) modifying css on the fly (c) extracting info from items in a list.

Enjoy. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
label
{
    width: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<script>
var locList = [ {name:'Australia', desc:'pop. 22,620,600', col:'green', bg:'yellow'}, {name:'New Zealand', desc:'pop. 4,405,200', col:'white', bg:'black'} ];
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

var dynamicCSS;

function selChange(element)
{
    var arrayIndex = element.value;
    if (arrayIndex != -1)
    {
        byId('poiName').value = locList[arrayIndex].name;
        byId('poiDesc').value = locList[arrayIndex].desc;

        var styleStr = "#poiName,#poiDesc{color: " + locList[arrayIndex].col + "; background-color: " + locList[arrayIndex].bg + "; }";
        dynamicCSS.innerHTML = styleStr;
    }
    else
    {
        byId('poiName').value = byId('poiDesc').value = 'No option selected';
        dynamicCSS.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function myInit()
{
    var st = document.createElement('style');
    st.innerHTML = '#poiName, #poiDesc{border:solid 2px green;}';
    document.body.appendChild(st);

    dynamicCSS = document.createElement('style');
    document.body.appendChild(dynamicCSS);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='myInit();'>
    <form id='myform'>
        <label for='optSel'>Option:</label>
        <select id='optSel' onchange='selChange(this);'>
            <option value='-1'>None selected</option>
            <option value='0'>Aus</option>
            <option value='1'>NZ</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for='poiName'>Name</label><input id='poiName'/>
        <br>
        <label for='poiDesc'>Desc</label><input id='poiDesc'/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would actually like to extract data stored in an array locLost[i] and populate them into the form elements "poiName" and "poiDesc". This block of code is within a for-loop.<p>

    locList[i].name into poiName
    locList[i].desc into poiDesc
<p>
How should I code to put these values into the respective form elements? Also, how could I add inputElement1 and inputElement2 to DOM then?
<p>
Thanks.

Comment: I've updapted my answer. Does this do what you want?